# Can't figure out output character encoding for MeCab

Tags: mecab

I'm trying to parse some Japanese text, and I can't seem to figure out the output encoding.

This is the output I'm getting:

```
これは ̾��,����,*,*,*,*,*
本   ̾��,����,*,*,*,*,*
です  ̾��,����,*,*,*,*,*
。   ̾��,������³,*,*,*,*,*
EOS
```

Steps I took:

1. `git clone https://github.com/taku910/mecab`
2. `cd mecab/mecab`
3. `./configure --enable-utf8-only --with-charset=utf8`
4. `make`
5. `sudo make install`
6. `mecab -o ~/Desktop/output.txt ~/Desktop/input.txt`, where `input.txt` contains "これは本です。"

Using OSX 10.15.3

Comment: What does `mecab -D` ("show dictionary information and exit") say? In my case, `mecab -D` says it will use IPADIC with `charset: utf8` and I'm curious if in your case default dictionary isn't UTF-8.

Comment: `charset: euc-jp`, so clearly not what I want

Comment: Great, so MeCab is fine, just reinstall the dictionary with utf-8. If you have Homebrew, you can just `brew install mecab-unidic` etc. (though they don't have the latest Unidic).